# Instance ID not invalidated when clear application data

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, instanceid

I have implemented `GCM 3.0` with `Instance ID API` for sending push notification to application using `Application` and `GCM` server.

Here is **[Instance ID API for GCM](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID)** documentation which i am referring.

When User direcltly uninstall application without logout then `GCM` gives **`"Not Registered"`** error for devices with the app uninstalled.

What i have to do is to remove useless `Device id tokens` from `Application server` for that i have tried with Uninstall of application then `Instance ID` is changed but when application data is cleared by User then `new Instance ID` will same as `previous Instance ID`.

while `Android GCM` documentation says:

> Instance ID is stable but may become invalid, if:
>
> - App deletes Instance ID
> - Device is factory reset
> - User uninstalls the app
> - User clears app data

is there any particular reason for this?

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that when you clear the app data you are still getting the same Instance ID when you call getToken()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Google says, "Instance ID **MAY** become invalid if ...".

Here is my findings while using GCM,

- Clearing an app in most cases doesn't change the instance ID, when you call getToken().
- All messages and topic messages will be delivered and shown, although the app is cleared and you didn't open in again (no getToken() is called).

Comment: GCM is now deprecated. The above does not appear to be the case for (Firebase) FCM - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId - which says the Instance ID ***will*** be deleted when the user clears the app data, etc.