# Clearing app data not clearing GCM token nor GCM subscribing topics

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, token

I had subscribed to topics from GCM and when I removed all app data by android settings, the GCM token is the same and GCM notification on topics are still available, so I get notifications which I don't want to receive.

My questions are:

- How can I get list all of subscribed topics from GCM?
- How can I remove all subscribed topics without knowing their names?
- Should the GCM token be changed after clearing app data or should all subscribed topics be removed automatically in this case?

Comment: For your first and second question, there is no feature to retrieve all topics, or remove them all without their names. For your third question, your registration token will be change, if you install your app in your device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can't only you can use tool for debug i suggest :)
   You have to save subscribed topics for example in sharedprefs. If you don't have token in sharedpreferences you should call  `instanceId.deleteInstanceID()`
2. Simply call  `instanceId.deleteInstanceID()`
3. Token will change rarely but when it changes you must resubscribe all your topics.

Also checkout [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34254015/gcm-re-subscribe-topics-after-ontokenrefresh/34769808#34769808)

---

**TOOL**

You can use [this](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#example_get_request) tool to debug :)

When i don't subscribe any topic i get something like this:

```
{
    "applicationVersion": "39",
    "connectDate": "2016-01-12",
    "application": "com.esportlivescore.develop.debug",
    "authorizedEntity": "114434000000000",
    "connectionType": "MOBILE",
    "appSigner": ".................",
    "platform": "ANDROID"
}
```

After i subscribe some topic:

```
{
    "applicationVersion": "39",
    "connectDate": "2016-01-12",
    "application": "com.esportlivescore.develop.debug",
    "authorizedEntity": "11443413691531",
    "rel": {
        "topics": {
            "match-28388-start": {
                "addDate": "2016-01-13"
            }
        }
    },
    "connectionType": "MOBILE",
    "appSigner": ".................",
    "platform": "ANDROID"
}
```

So somple usage. I use Advanced REST Client ([plugin for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/reviews?hl=en-US&utm_source=ARC))

### HTTP GET Request

```
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/<TOKEN>?details=true
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
```

**TOKEN** in url : `token obtainet from google`

**key** : can be found in Google Developer Console / GCM Console

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get list all of subscribing topics from gcm?

The current version of GCM doesn't provide a method to do this.

> How can I remove all of subcribing topics without knowing their names?

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#unregistration-and-unsubscription) indicates [InstanceId.deleteInstanceID()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID.html#deleteInstanceID()) will do this.

> Should GCM token be changed after clear app data or removed all
>   subscribing topics in this case automatically?

Although the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID) implies that token registrations and subscriptions are removed if the user clears app data, that is not true in the current version of GCM.  The issue is discussed in the answer to this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33252750/instance-id-not-invalidated-when-clear-application-data).