# GCM re-subscribe topics after onTokenRefresh()

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

From Google Developer website, I found that GCM Token may be changed after period of time:

> The Instance ID service initiates callbacks periodically (for example,
>   every 6 months), requesting that your app refreshes its tokens. It may
>   also initiate callbacks when:
>
> There are security issues; for example, SSL or platform issues.
>
> Device information is no longer valid; for example, backup and restore.
>
> The Instance ID service is otherwise affected.

I have an android app using GCM Topic subscriptions to send push notification, in this case, when token has been refreshed, do I need to re-subscribe all topics again or GCM server will automatically do it ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I did the research for a while and cannot find the doc under the GCM topic tag. I checked the code here :https://github.com/google/gcm/blob/master/samples/android/gcm-demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/ui/TopicsFragment.java#L83-L137 for the topic. Finally, I saw this doc: https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation#refresh_tokens and I think that if you refresh the token, you should update the new token instead of old one on your server, but before this, you have to check the topic, and `unsubscribeTopic` for old token and put the new one in the topic.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested that when token is refreshed (you receive a new token) you have to register all topics again.

Also checkout [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739519/clearing-app-data-not-clearing-gcm-token-nor-gcm-subscribing-topics/34786499#34786499)

Sample test:

1. Get token ("...b43sCSdoEDkU54SIWll3hbDVsd7E1UdwlAvp4LP")
2. Register for topic.
3. Send notification for topic
4. Works!
5. Restart few times app and still get notification for topic
6. Force call

`instanceID.getToken(defaultSenderId, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE)`;

7. Token refreshed ("...XVT_pZq7fy_vKmskiGpDXMyqdAF6ODl_46JMdi5")
8. Send notification for topic. I don't get it!

More details:

**Tool #1**
Use [this](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#example_get_request) to check google gcm data

1. Reinstall app
2. Get new token ("")

Response from **tool #1**

```
{
    "applicationVersion": "39",
    "connectDate": "2016-01-12",
    "application": "com.esportlivescore.develop.debug",
    "authorizedEntity": "11443413691531",
    "connectionType": "MOBILE",
    "appSigner": ".................",
    "platform": "ANDROID"
}
```

3. Subscribe for topic

Response from **tool #1**

```
{
    "applicationVersion": "39",
    "connectDate": "2016-01-12",
    "application": "com.esportlivescore.develop.debug",
    "authorizedEntity": "11443413691531",
    "rel": {
        "topics": {
            "match-28388-start": {
                "addDate": "2016-01-13"
            }
        }
    },
    "connectionType": "MOBILE",
    "appSigner": ".................",
    "platform": "ANDROID"
}
```

4. Messages for topic are working
5. Request new token (refresh)
6. Google resend me old token :)
7. Again...
8. Now i don't have any subscriptions :(