# Create a topic in Firebase from Android

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging and I'm trying to create topics programatically from my android app. I cannot find a way to create a topic, but there's this method called `subscribeToTopic(String topic)` that allows me to subscribe the device to a topic and get it's messages. How can I **CREATE** a topic from my android app? Is there a way to do it in Java so I can also create topics in my server? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Create Topic in FCM Notifications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367292/how-to-create-topic-in-fcm-notifications)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! When you do `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("newTopic")`, if the topic called "newTopic" doesn't exits, it is created and the user is subscribed to that new topic.

Comment: i already made this but there it is not created until now about more than 12 hours

Comment: Unfortunately that's the minimum amount of time for Firebase to create the topic, it sucks but you can't do anything to fix it...

Comment: Where in the FIrebase console may i see all the users who are subscribing to a topic(eg "sports") from my android App?

Comment: @user3833732 take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987821/get-all-subscribed-topics-from-firebase-cloud-messaging

Comment: @Nahue I did check it, but it doesnt give me a list of ALL the users presently subscribed to a particular topic, any ideas?

Comment: @user3833732 take into consideration that it takes like 12 hours to a device to get subscribed to a topic, so maybe you're not getting them all because you didn't wait those 12 hours