# Firebase messaging (web) - get topics results in 401

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get a list of topics subscribed to via the firebase API.

My firebase project has an `api-key`, which is known to the client. The client has also generated a `messaging-token` (which I guess is really a google iid). So both are public information.

I am attempting a GET to the following url (based on these [google iid instructions](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#example_get_request))

`https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/<messaging-token>?details=true&Authorization:key=<api-key>`

I also have a header `Authorization:key=<api-key>` as the instructions are little ambiguous

I am getting 401 responses.

I have done this a few months ago but then I had to provide a secret server key, which the firebase UI described as legacy then, and which is now not available. There is a private key in the UI but that also results in `401`s.

[image: screenshot of firebase UI]

What do I need to do?

Comment: On the server side, the App Default Credentials should suffice for authentication and the auth should be baked in to the server-side Firebase Admin SDK library you use, right? [It says](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-topics) `The Firebase Admin SDK allows you to perform basic topic management tasks from the server side.`

Comment: Yes, I have read this but it among the 'basic' tasks does not seem to be get all my subscriptions

Comment: What server environment are you using to get the list of subscriptions

Comment: None as yet. I'm trying to understand the docs to know what secret information, if any, is needed to get these subscriptions, so that I can work out how to architect it

Comment: I see. Well, I can tell you that the raw REST API is going to be the most time consuming and complicated approach. The client libraries are the way to go.

Comment: yes, but the client libraries only support "basic topic management" and I need something that is not included, so I need to find another solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all subscribed topics from firebase cloud messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987821/get-all-subscribed-topics-from-firebase-cloud-messaging)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250715/discussion-between-simon-h-and-ronnie-royston).